Using @mui/x-data-grid library in react typescript, needed to apply filter on multiple columns and filter the data
I am using @mui/x-data-grid library for data grid. My requirement is that I need to filter the multiple columns at a time. If I add filter on one column I get the result, If I try to add the filter on second column, first filtered result disappears and I get the original data. Also, I need the filtered list which I applied on the columns with multiple conditions based on the columns so that I can remove it again and I should get the result for remaining filter.
I have tried following example, where I am getting the filter for columns but I am not getting the filtered list on click of filter icon. Also, I am sure my example does not meet any requirement so I am expecting to example where I can get the function which will meet the result.
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 150 },
  { field: "age", headerName: "Age", type: "number", width: 110 },
  { field: "status", headerName: "Status", width: 150 },
];

const initialRows = [
  { id: 1, name: "Alice", age: 25, status: "High" },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 30, status: "Medium" },
  { id: 3, name: "Bob", age: 30, status: "Medium" },
  { id: 4, name: "Bob1", age: 45, status: "High" },
  { id: 5, name: "Bob2", age: 55, status: "Medium" },
  { id: 6, name: "Charlie", age: 35, status: "Low" },
  { id: 7, name: "Alice", age: 60, status: "Low" },
];

export default function CustomMultiFilterDataGrid() {
  const [filteredRows, setFilteredRows] = React.useState(initialRows);
  const [activeFilters, setActiveFilters] = React.useState([]);

  const applyFilters = (rows, filters) => {
    return rows.filter((row) => {
      return filters.every((filter) => {
        const value = row[filter.field];
        if (value === undefined || value === null || !filter.value)
          return false;

        switch (filter.operator) {
          case "contains":
            return value
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(filter.value.toLowerCase());
          case "equals":
            return (
              value.toString().toLowerCase() === filter.value.toLowerCase()
            );
          case "startsWith":
            return value
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .startsWith(filter.value.toLowerCase());
          case "endsWith":
            return value
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .endsWith(filter.value.toLowerCase());
          case "gte":
            return Number(value) >= Number(filter.value);
          case "lte":
            return Number(value) <= Number(filter.value);
          default:
            return true;
        }
      });
    });
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (newFilterModel) => {
    setActiveFilters((prevFilters) => {
      const newFilter = newFilterModel.items[0];
      if (newFilter && newFilter.value) {
        const updatedFilters = prevFilters.filter(
          (filter) => filter.field !== newFilter.field
        );
        updatedFilters.push(newFilter);
        const updatedRows = applyFilters(initialRows, updatedFilters);
        setFilteredRows(updatedRows);
        return updatedFilters;
      }
      return prevFilters;
    });

    // Apply filters to the initial rows and store only the filtered records
    if (newFilterModel.items.length === 0) {
      // If all filters are removed, reset to original data
      setFilteredRows(initialRows);
      setActiveFilters([]);
    }
  };

  console.log("activefilers==>", activeFilters);
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={filteredRows}
        columns={columns}
        onFilterModelChange={handleFilterChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


I have added my expected output to be like as below image

